# MS Access Form - Horizontal Anchor Affecting Data Update

Tags: ms-access

Running Access 2007 with a databound form.

The form Record Source is set to a query, and all fields in the form have a defined Control Source; nothing fancy, just field names. The form is a Single form with record navigation buttons which perform a "Next Record" and "Previous Record" actions.

As I navigate the records the controls in the header update correctly. However, if I change a control Horizontal Anchor property to "Right" the fields no longer update on record navigation. This is observed for both text box and combo box controls. I can switch the anchoring back to "Left" and the updating works as it should.

Is there some reason anchoring would affect a control updating of in an Access form? Or is this a bug that has been observed before?

The only workaround I can think of is to assign the control text/value property in the form OnCurrent event, but this seems somewhat sloppy. Am I missing something here?

Comment: when you say "no longer update on record navigation", what exactly happens? do the fields get empty or have values from previous record?

Comment: Looks like a bug. I was able to replicate it (2007). Just a suggestion: what if you do something like Me.Refresh on the Form_Current event?

Comment: Ah, such a simple solution. The Refresh method corrects this problem. For some reason I was assuming an 'On Current' event was already refreshing the form and didn't even try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug. Refreshing the Form on the Form_Current event solves the problem:

```
Private Sub From_Current()

Me.Refresh

End Sub
```